# Calling HTTPS request on google cloud function getting connect connect to server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm calling a https endpoint on google cloud function, with http triggers, but I got

```
{
   "type": "connection_error",
   "message": "Error occured while connecting to First API",
   "error": {
      "code": "ENOTFOUND",
      "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
      "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
      "hostname": "api-cert.payeezy.com",
      "host": "api-cert.payeezy.com",
      "port": 443
   }
}
```

Same exact code works on amazon lambda, does anyone know if google cloud function need special tweaks calling https servers? I tried using cors but still giving the same error.

my code is a very generic http call using payeezy api

```js
    var nonce = Math.random() * 1000000000000000000;
    var timeInMillis = new Date().getTime();
    var requestJSON=JSON.stringify({
            method: 'credit_card',
            amount: '1299',
            currency_code: 'USD',
            credit_card: {
                card_number: '4788250000028291',
                cvv: '123',
                type: 'visa',
                exp_date: '1230',
                cardholder_name: 'Tom Eck'
            },
            billing_address: {
                street: '225 Liberty Street',
                city: 'NYC',
                state_province: 'NY',
                zip_postal_code: '10281',
                country: 'US'
            }
        });
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'apikey': apikey,
        'token': merchant_token,
        'nonce': nonce,
        'timestamp':timeInMillis,
        'Authorization': getAuthorizationHeader(apikey, apisecret, requestJSON, merchant_token, nonce, timeInMillis)
    };
    
    var options = {
        host: "api-cert.payeezy.com",
        path: '/v1/transactions',
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers
    };
    var req1 = http.request(options);
    req1.on('response', responseHandler(callback));
    req1.on('error', errorHandler(callback));
    req1.write(requestJSON);
    req1.end();
```

Comment: Its clear from error that `api-cert.payeezy.com` doesn't exist.

Comment: You cannot make external API requests on the Spark plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to James Daniel's comment, I notice google function can only call google's own service using spark plan.
There's an outbound networking row in the pricing page
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/